# ASA 5505 stops local internet when connected to VPN

Tags: vpn, cisco-asa, l2tp

I have a Cisco ASA router running firmware 8.2(5) which hosts an internal LAN on 192.168.30.0/24.

I have used the VPN Wizard to setup L2TP access and I can connect in fine from a Windows box and can ping hosts behind the VPN router.

However, when connected to the VPN I can no longer ping out to my internet or browse web pages. I would like to be able to access the VPN, and also browse the internet at the same time - I understand this is called split tunneling (have ticked the setting in the wizard but to no effect) and if so how do I do this?

Alternatively, if split tunneling is a pain to setup, then making the connected VPN client have internet access from the ASA WAN IP would be OK.

```
names
!
interface Ethernet0/0
 switchport access vlan 2
!
interface Ethernet0/1
!
interface Vlan1
 nameif inside
 security-level 100
 ip address 192.168.30.1 255.255.255.0 
!
interface Vlan2
 nameif outside
 security-level 0
 ip address 208.74.158.58 255.255.255.252 
!
ftp mode passive
access-list inside_nat0_outbound extended permit ip any 10.10.10.0 255.255.255.128 
access-list inside_nat0_outbound extended permit ip 192.168.30.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.30.192 255.255.255.192 
access-list DefaultRAGroup_splitTunnelAcl standard permit 192.168.30.0 255.255.255.0 
access-list DefaultRAGroup_splitTunnelAcl_1 standard permit 192.168.30.0 255.255.255.0 
pager lines 24
logging asdm informational
mtu inside 1500
mtu outside 1500
ip local pool LANVPNPOOL 192.168.30.220-192.168.30.249 mask 255.255.255.0
icmp unreachable rate-limit 1 burst-size 1
no asdm history enable
arp timeout 14400
global (outside) 1 interface
nat (inside) 0 access-list inside_nat0_outbound
nat (inside) 1 192.168.30.0 255.255.255.0
route outside 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 208.74.158.57 1
timeout xlate 3:00:00
timeout conn 1:00:00 half-closed 0:10:00 udp 0:02:00 icmp 0:00:02
timeout sunrpc 0:10:00 h323 0:05:00 h225 1:00:00 mgcp 0:05:00 mgcp-pat 0:05:00
timeout sip 0:30:00 sip_media 0:02:00 sip-invite 0:03:00 sip-disconnect 0:02:00
timeout sip-provisional-media 0:02:00 uauth 0:05:00 absolute
timeout tcp-proxy-reassembly 0:01:00
timeout floating-conn 0:00:00
dynamic-access-policy-record DfltAccessPolicy
http server enable
http 192.168.30.0 255.255.255.0 inside
snmp-server enable traps snmp authentication linkup linkdown coldstart
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-AES-256-MD5 esp-aes-256 esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-DES-SHA esp-des esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-3DES-SHA esp-3des esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-DES-MD5 esp-des esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-AES-192-MD5 esp-aes-192 esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-3DES-MD5 esp-3des esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-AES-256-SHA esp-aes-256 esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-AES-128-SHA esp-aes esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-AES-192-SHA esp-aes-192 esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-AES-128-MD5 esp-aes esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec transform-set TRANS_ESP_3DES_SHA esp-3des esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec transform-set TRANS_ESP_3DES_SHA mode transport
crypto ipsec security-association lifetime seconds 28800
crypto ipsec security-association lifetime kilobytes 4608000
crypto dynamic-map SYSTEM_DEFAULT_CRYPTO_MAP 65535 set transform-set ESP-AES-128-SHA ESP-AES-128-MD5 ESP-AES-192-SHA ESP-AES-192-MD5 ESP-AES-256-SHA ESP-AES-256-MD5 ESP-3DES-SHA ESP-3DES-MD5 ESP-DES-SHA ESP-DES-MD5 TRANS_ESP_3DES_SHA
crypto map outside_map 65535 ipsec-isakmp dynamic SYSTEM_DEFAULT_CRYPTO_MAP
crypto map outside_map interface outside
crypto isakmp enable outside
crypto isakmp policy 10
 authentication pre-share
 encryption 3des
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
telnet timeout 5
ssh timeout 5
console timeout 0
dhcpd auto_config outside
!

threat-detection basic-threat
threat-detection statistics access-list
no threat-detection statistics tcp-intercept
webvpn
group-policy DefaultRAGroup internal
group-policy DefaultRAGroup attributes
 dns-server value 192.168.30.3
 vpn-tunnel-protocol l2tp-ipsec 
 split-tunnel-policy tunnelspecified
 split-tunnel-network-list value DefaultRAGroup_splitTunnelAcl_1
username user password Cj7W5X7wERleAewO8ENYtg== nt-encrypted privilege 0
tunnel-group DefaultRAGroup general-attributes
 address-pool LANVPNPOOL
 default-group-policy DefaultRAGroup
tunnel-group DefaultRAGroup ipsec-attributes
 pre-shared-key *****
tunnel-group DefaultRAGroup ppp-attributes
 no authentication chap
 authentication ms-chap-v2
!
class-map inspection_default
 match default-inspection-traffic
!
!
policy-map type inspect dns preset_dns_map
 parameters
  message-length maximum client auto
  message-length maximum 512
policy-map global_policy
 class inspection_default
  inspect dns preset_dns_map 
  inspect ftp 
  inspect h323 h225 
  inspect h323 ras 
  inspect rsh 
  inspect rtsp 
  inspect esmtp 
  inspect sqlnet 
  inspect skinny  
  inspect sunrpc 
  inspect xdmcp 
  inspect sip  
  inspect netbios 
  inspect tftp 
  inspect ip-options 
!
service-policy global_policy global
prompt hostname context 
: end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Which client software are you using to connect?  Split tunneling is set up, but I believe you'll need to be connecting with the Cisco client software for it to function.

Anyway, to get the VPN client's internet traffic to make it out to the internet, looks like all you need is:

```
same-security-traffic permit intra-interface
nat (outside) 1 192.168.30.0 255.255.255.0
```